# Input Shape for Keras Model with multiple one-hot arrays

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, input

I don't quite understand how the input shape and dimensions for a keras model works when trying to use multiple one hot encoded arrays.

For example, this is my feature state containing 9 one-hot encoded arrays.

```
 features = [[first_one_hot] + [second_one_hot] + \
               [third_one_hot] + [fourth_one_hot] + [sixt_one_hot] + [seventh_one_hot]+ ...]
```

having a shape of: (3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 10, 10, 10), where:

> Shape: a shape (30,4,10) means an array or tensor with 3 dimensions, containing 30 elements in the first dimension, 4 in the second and 10 in the third, totaling 30 * 4 * 10 = 1200 elements or numbers.

If I just unpack each of my one hot arrays, my model works given a shape of (1, 56) - but as of my understanding, the model does not quite know which values correspond to which one hot by doing so.

**Question 1**
First of all, am I understanding right that each of the features concatenated in the array above should be separated, instead of using a (1, 56) array as I mentioned? Lets say, instead of:

[1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,...] use:

[1,0,0], [1,0,0,0], ...

If so, how should I give the separated onehot's to the model? I'm new at machine learning, so this might be a strange question to ask.

**Question 2**
If so, what could be the advantage of also grouping thematically similar onehots into separate input layers?

My build_model right now uss just one input-dim with (1,56) layer size:

```
 def _build_model(self, hl1_dims, hl2_dims, hl3_dims, input_layer_size, output_layer_size, optimizer, loss):
    model = Sequential()

    # My input_layer_size is set to 9, as I have 9 dimensions
    model.add(Dense(hl1_dims, input_dim=input_layer_size))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(Activation('relu'))

    # Second Hidden Layer
    ...
```

As of my understanding, I could also use multiple input layers something like that:

```
input_3d = Input(shape=(3,))
input_4d = Input(shape=(4,))
input_5d = Input(shape=(5,))
input_10d = Input(shape=(10,))

# multiple branches, for example:
branch_3d = Dense(32, activation='relu')(input_3d)
branch_3d = Dense(32, activation='relu')(branch_3d)
m_3d = Model(inputs=input_3d, outputs=branch_3d)

 # Combine all output of branches
combined = Concatenate(axis=1)([m_3d.output, m_4d.output, m_5d.output, m_10d.output])

# Apply FC Layer
out = Dense(16, activation='relu')(combined)
out = Dense(output_layer_size, activation='linear')(out)

# Model accepts inputs of all branches and output action space based on output_layer_size
model = Model(inputs=[m_3d.input, m_4d.input, m_5d.input, m_10d.input], outputs=out)
```

I tried above implementation but never really got it to work, mostly got errors like:

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_input to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (1, 1, 9)
```

But as I said, I'm not even sure if you would split categorical inputs into separate layers or if it's best practice to just combine all categorical features into one shape. Would really much appreciate any input on this.

Comment: As of know with my research, I think I have a fundamental problem in building the model. The input features have different shapes. Until now I tried to concatenate the whole state into one and feed it into the neural network. What I'm trying to understand now is - different input features, few of them with different shapes, seem to have to be splitted into separate input vectors with corresponding shape using Keras Functional API. After every input has been loaded, the network is slowly concatenated together to obtain one single output vector from the neural net.

Comment: Information is bit confusing. Can you please share your Dataset or share the snapshot of your Data, for example by running the command, `pandas_dataframe.head()` so that we can actually understand how your Data is. Thanks!

Comment: Hei @TensorflowSupport sorry for my late reply. Did some edit on my first post as I changed quite some implementation in the meanwhile. Hope it's clear enough, else let me know I'll try to clarify more.